# Android ExoPlayer takes more time on buffering

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, buffering

I want to load URL from server. But ExoPlayer takes more time on buffering. There is no error while playing video.
My code is below

```
try {
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
        exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);;
        Uri videouri = Uri.parse(file);
        DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videouri, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
        exoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
        exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("LOGTAG", "Error : " + e.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Simply Set it Like that:

```
    ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
    playView.setPlayer(player);
    player.addMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse("url"));
    player.prepare();
    player.play();
```

Comment: I have tried it before, But buffering takes much time as the first time.

Comment: Can u send me the link of url I will try a solution if its working I will let uh no :)

Comment: Here is url, I am using. 
https://thailotterytv.com/videos/mblank.mp4